# Flash CS 5.5 Professional requires 32-bit JVM when publishing for iOS

Tags: java, ios, flash, air, jvm

When trying to publish my file to AIR for iOS I get the following error:

```
Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version.
```

I'm on Mac OS (Mavericks) and have both java 6 (which supports 32-bit) and 7 (which does not) installed. I've verified I can launch a 32-bit jvm from the terminal with "`java -d32`".

Interestingly, it publishes to AIR with no problems when it's not to iOS.

How can I get Flash to use the correct version of Java? I've tried setting JAVA_HOME to point to version 6 in /etc/profile with still no luck.

Thanks for reading, I will really appreciate the help!!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?